# Cual es el formato correcto para guardar fecha y hora en SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo este código para guardar la hora y la fecha en la que se hizo login, pero me sale error

```
var fecha = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
var hora = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt");
string sesion = "INSERT INTO Sesion VALUES("+sesionusr()+","+fecha+","+hora+")";
con.consulta(sesion, "Sesion");
```

En la tabla tengo Campos de fecha y hora divididos DATE y TIME(7)

Comment: Probaste dejando todo en una sola variable, asignarle el datetime Now y simplemente pasar esa variable en el insert despues de la sesion, no necesitas pasar fecha y hora por separado, a no ser de que asi lo necesites, y pon tambien el codigo de que error te sale

Comment: en sql lo ideal es definir el campo tipo datetime y desde c# pasarle un datetime.now.tostring() esto registra fecha, hora, min y seg en el mismo campo

Comment: ¿Por qué no mejor un solo campo con la fecha y hora? Si usas `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy HH:mm:ss");` puedes obtener el formato que buscas. Y el campo lo declaras como DateTime

Comment: Puse fecha y hora en un mismo campo, pero todavia mesale este error : 'Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '12'.' Puse el string asi string sesion = "INSERT INTO Sesion VALUES("+sesionusr()+","+fh;

Comment: es mas el "tt" no lo acepta el campo datetime a menos que uses un campo de tipo nvarchar o varchar pero no es lo ideal para trabajar con fechas.

Comment: sql te guarda el tiemo en formato 24 horas no puedes guardar AM o PM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo más práctico es tener un solo campo del tipo `Datetime` donde insertar la fecha y la hora conjuntamente. También lo más práctico es delegar esa inserción en la propia base de datos, por lo que quedaría así:

```
string sesion = "INSERT INTO Sesion VALUES ('" + sesionusr() + "', GetDate())";
```

Si deseas enviarle la fecha desde C#, deberás hacerlo con un formato correcto:

```
var fechahora = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
string sesion = "INSERT INTO Sesion VALUES ('" + sesionusr() + "', '" + fechahora + "')";
```

La variable `fechahora` la introducimos rodeada de comillas simples.
SQL Server guarda la fecha en un formato interno, sin formato reconocible, y la muestra dependiendo de la herramienta cliente, su configuración internacional o bien por el formato que le indiques en la sentencia.

Pero para obtener dia/mes/año hora:minutos am/pm [no tiene conversión directa](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), para ello deberías convertir la fecha y concatenar algunos carácteres:

```
Select convert(varchar(10),fecha, 101) + ' ' + right(convert(varchar(32),fecha,100),8)
```

Para versiónes 2012 o posterior lo tenemos más fácil:

```
select FORMAT(Fecha,'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:s tt')
```